# Power BI Developer Visual not present; pbiviz start is listening

Tags: node.js, powerbi

I have followed instructions for Power BI's [Developer Visual Setup](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/tools/DebugVisualSetup.md) and am able to successfully run `pbiviz start` against NPM's `powerbi-visuals-tools` running Node.js 6.10.0 (x64):

```
info   Building visual...
done   build complete

info   Starting server...
info   Server listening on port 8080.
```

My Power BI is configured to allow developer visual for testing. However, Power BI doesn't show the developer visual button. It seems this is due to PBI not being able to connect to the server on port 8080, so I checked `netstat -an` to see if the port is truly open, which it is:

```
>netstat -an | findstr 8080
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

I then tried to connect to the port (127.0.0.1:8080) from PuTTY as telnet, and it immediately fails with "Connection closed by remote host". If it's any indication, when I kill `pbiviz`, the open 8080 port lines disappear.

Is there something else that needs to be done to make this port available?

I discovered that I can run `pbiviz package`, generate a .pbiviz file, and load it from PBI by clicking <kbd>...</kbd> -> <kbd>Import a custom visual</kbd>, and the test visual that I created works. So PBI is playing nicely with the sample project created by `pbiviz new MyVisualName`. It seems this may be a Node.js server issue, not so much Power BI?

Comment: I got the same issue, running Node.JS **V6.10.0**

Comment: Go to: https:// localhost:8080 (HTTPS is needed), if You see some javascript, then it probably works & problem is somewhere between PowerBI & communication with the server.

Comment: Also found this: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/can-t-connect-visual-server-running-local-host-and-have/td-p/73166

Answer (score 2):

First, try reinstalling the SSL certificate. Restart your computer.
Second, if you're using PBI in a browser other than Chrome, switch to Chrome.

If you still can't view it in Chrome, go to https://localhost:8080/assets/status
Chrome should show a warning message. Click  Advanced, then proceed to unsafe version. Then go back to PBI. You should see your visual.

Answer (score 0):

I think its the proxy that block the connection between your host and PBI

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a problem with your SSL Certificate ->

in cmd:

`pbiviz --install-cert`

Edit: I made the exact same mistake because its not directly included in the tutorial.

Additional information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/create-ssl-certificate